# Facing problem to access resource file in maven project

Tags: java

I am unableto access `myXml.xml` file through `MyStaticClass.java` class from following project structure.
If I put this xml file somewhere under java folder I can access it by:

```
MyStaticClass.class.getResourceAsStream("[...]/myXml.xml");
```

But can't access from resources folder, neither by absolute path (/myXml.xml) nor by relative path starting from app folder. Is something special with maven project or I am doing some mistake?
Please help me resolve this issue.

```
my-app  
`-- src  
     -- main  
        |-- java  
        |   `-- com  
        |       `-- mycompany  
        |           `-- app  
        |               `-- App.java  
        |               `-- MyStaticClass.java  
        `-- resources  
            `-- myXml.xml
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you calling `getResourceAsStream` in a unit test or from running your app from the artifact (.jar probably) produced after the package goal runs?  If not, `myXml.xml` will not be on your classpath.

If you are doing this in a unit test, then `myXml.xml` needs to be in `src/test/resources` and not `src/main/resources` .

Comment: No, Not running in unit test. Rather running directly from source for debugging

Comment: Well... how are you running it in eclipse?  Are you using the m2 eclipse plugin?  It sounds to me like resources isn't being included in the class path like it should.  I'm not familiar enough with eclipse to know in this case.  I do know that, courtesy of the packaging in maven, myXml.xml will end up in the root of your .jar assuming a directory structure like the one you already pasted.

Comment: I am running through eclipse launcher. It is just as I am running compiled byte code (not packaged into jar) on command prompt

Comment: Got your point that file would be available on package root but first I need to to debug. I guess there should be a way to accomplish both purposes

Comment: If you are using `mvn eclipse:eclipse` to generate a .project file,  go make sure that src/main/resources is on the classpath.  Try running `mvn eclipse:eclipse` again to see if it does it for you automatically.

Comment: Once again I got to know "how stupid I am". Thanks @whaley for this discovery